# How to show items when the command is typed (OnKeyUp) in python?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a list of shop items and i want those items to show when the command is typed.

```
    @app_commands.command(name="delete", description="delete an item from shop")
    async def delete(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, name: str):
```

Within the name part i want the items to show like the example below

[image]

so, is there any specific way i have to/can do this?

Comment: Those are called `choices`, you can see the official example of how to make one yourself [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/app_commands/transformers.py#L80-L89).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify this code to show what you want:

```
from discord import app_commands

choosable = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"] #a list of the items (develop your function to get what you would like to get back as an option)
choices = [app_commands.Choice(name=choice, value=choice) for choice in choosable] # don't have to touch this unless you want to change varibale names

@bot.tree.command(name="choose")
@app_commands.choices(option=choices)
async def choose(interaction:discord.Interaction,option:app_commands.Choice[str]): #showing the options 
    await interaction.response.send_message(option.value,ephemeral=True) # send back the chosen value.
```